Calculate day difference between one date and multiple dates in the same column
I have an input table like this



date
amount




2011-01-02
50


2011-01-03
40


2011-01-04
20


2011-01-05
10



Am looking to group it and create a one-to-many where the difference of date A1 is compared to every other date (A1 - A2, A1 - A3, A1 - A4 ) and repeated for the rest (A2 - A1, A2 - A3, etc)



date
difference in days
date compared




2011-01-02
1 day
2011-01-03


2011-01-02
2 days
2011-01-04


2011-01-02
3 days
2011-01-05


2011-01-03
-1 days
2011-01-02


2011-01-03
1 days
2011-01-04


2011-01-03
2 days
2011-01-05


2011-01-04
-2 days
2011-01-02


2011-01-04
-1 days
2011-01-03


2011-01-04
1 days
2011-01-05




what environment are you talking about?

it's sql in apache-zeppelin notebook

Assuming you are using PostgreSQL (your question doesn't clarify), you can use the DATE_PART function to subtract the days between dates:
SELECT
    a.date
    , b.date as compared_date
    , DATE_PART('day', b.date) - DATE_PART('day', a.date) as diff
FROM mytable as a
CROSS JOIN mytable as b

Where mytable is your original table.
We use the CROSS JOIN to link all dates from the table to all dates, then the second step is to use DATE_PART to find the difference between the two.
Feel free to learn more by checking out this link.
